# Couchbase N1qlQuery: use key value from select

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have this queries:

```
select otherDocKey from bucket use keys '1234'
update bucket use keys 'hear I need the result of the first query' set ...
```

I want to do something like that:

```
update bucket use keys (select otherDocKey from bucket use keys '1234') set kuku = 3
```

but the response I get is:

`[
  {
    "code": 5030,
    "msg": "Missing or invalid primary key map[otherDocKey:\"56443\"] of type map[string]interface {}."
  }
]`

is there a way to do that in one query?

I am using couchbase version 4.5

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298550/using-n1ql-with-document-keys) looks very close to what you need

Comment: @summerbulb this is select with join it different. I can't join on update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is that the nested subquery returns a json result. I.e., the query:

`select otherDocKey from bucket use keys '1234'`

will return a result that looks like:

```
{"otherDocKey":"This_is_the_key_for_the_other_doc"}
```

But you don't want json, you just want the value from the json. For that you need to use 'select raw'. E.g.,

```
select raw otherDocKey from bucket use keys '1234'
```

That should give you a result that looks like:

```
["This_is_the_key_for_the_other_doc"]
```

When the subquery returns that kind of result, the "use keys" should work properly.